# How to select syn packets going to given destination port with tcpdump

Tags: tcpdump

I'm trying to capture syn packets going to a given destination port with `tcpdump` with the following command :

```
tcpdump dst port 80 "(tcp-syn) !=0"
```

but it says

> tcp: syntax error

Any idea how to select those two filters ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your command:

1. You're missing logical operator `and` between port and packet type
2. `tcp-syn` is a constant - because of this the comparison in quotes is always true.

This should behave correctly:

> tcpdump dst port 80 and "tcp[tcpflags] & tcp-syn != 0"

Comment: yeah I found that out thanks, can you take a look at another thread maybe you could help me http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/298619/why-tcpdump-captures-many-packets-with-tcp-syn-0-but-not-with-tcptcpfla